# не устанавливаются cookie в кроссдоменном запросе

Tags: jquery, nginx, http, cors

Проблема следующая. Не могу установить cookie по кроссдоменному запросу.

Локально стоит Open server c Nginx.

Конфиг Nginx:

```
 server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:80;  
    server_name test.ru;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

    location / {
        proxy_intercept_errors on;  
        recursive_error_pages on;  
        proxy_buffering off;  
        proxy_pass https://tamaq.kz;  
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }

    more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";

   ....
```

отправляю запрос jquery:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    type:"POST",
    data:params,
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success:function(data) {
        resolve(data)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        reject(jqXHR)
    }
});
```

Заголовки от сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 12:11:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=120
Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=688334968920c44b6ceabe1a8bd4205f9ce5c4ad-
sessionid=5450c34f-1980-440f-bbf8-1662fc201bf0; Path=/; HTTPOnly
Request-Time: 144
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Но куки не устанавливаются. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Какой браузер? Как вы проверяете, что куки не устанавливаются?
Вообще, лучше завести в /etc/hosts какие-нибудь «настоящие» домены, потому что для localhost у браузеров может быть какая-нибудь нетривиальная логика.

Comment: Или воспользоваться публичными доменами типа `app.localtest.me` http://www.fidian.com/programming/public-dns-pointing-to-localhost

Comment: @AlexeyTen проверяю в хроме. Да, тут система сложнее. Пришлось на windows ставить Open Server и при запросе к test.ru  проксировать на  https://tamaq.kz;  так "побороли" CORS. Но куки почему не ставятся при post запросе. А при get запросе ставятся

Comment: Стоит сходить в настройки Хрома на предмет «Block third-party cookies and site data». Так и как проверяли что куки не устанавливаются?

Comment: Да, точно был выключена эта настройка. Но всё равно, что то не работает. Проверяю в панеле разработчика  Application -> cookies

Comment: Так это же кука от другого домена. На вашем `localhost:4200` её и не должно быть

Comment: Но при get запросе почему то ставится. У меня система какая: localhost:4200 - ember;
test.ru - nginx, который проксирует на https://tamaq.kz;
https://tamaq.kz; сайт с апишками

Comment: Сегодня рылся целый день что бы установить их кросс доменно. И по сути нужно было сделать так: поставить `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200;` (указав именно сайт, а не *), поставить ` add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';` для утсановки кук и добавить в $.ajax -  `xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }`

Comment: Но как то они не заводятся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была из-за домена  test.ru. 
Система работала так фронт (**localhost**) обращается к по локальному адресу(**test.ru**), который является прокси для АПИ (**https://example.com**).

В nginx просто избавился от ненужной прослойки test.ru, заменив её на localhost.
Теперь схема стала такой:

> localhost:4200 => localhost => example.com

То есть запрос перестал быть кроссдоменным.